# Adding a Polygon to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

How to add an polygon to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

Example: The script underneath will create a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. I would like to add a polygon which consists of a large square around the existing polygons.

```
   library(rgdal)
   dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
   Scotland <- readOGR(dsn=dsn , layer="scot_BNG")
   plot(Scotland)
```

[image]

Preferred end result:

[image]

It is important that the rectangle becomes part of the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. Since I have to do some calculation of the dataframe. So manually adding a visual layer of a square is insufficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code creates a rectangle that encloses the original spatial polygons and adds this as a spatial polygon to the original shape.

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

dsn <- system.file("vectors", package = "rgdal")[1]
Scotland <- readOGR(dsn=dsn , layer="scot_BNG")

# change the width parameter to make the rectangle the desired size
# this results in an extent object that surrounds the original shape
eScotland <- extent(gBuffer(Scotland, width = 50000))
# turn the extent into a Spatial Polygon
pScotland <- as(eScotland, 'SpatialPolygons')
crs(pScotland) <- crs(Scotland)
newScotland <- bind(pScotland, Scotland)
plot(newScotland)
```

[image]